# How to have delete cell button like iOS 9 mail application (image and text )

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I have a small question.

How can I have a swipe delete cell button like iOS 9 mail application(image + text )?

I found this method but my image is white, and I can't change background color if I make this :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {  
    let deleteButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Destructive, title:"\nDelete", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
    self.tableView.dataSource?.tableView?(self.tableView,commitEditingStyle: .Delete,
            forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)

    return
})

    deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "icon")!)
    return [deleteButton]
}
```

Thank you :)